# Preserve git remotes

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

I have fixed network of git remotes and I would like them to be attached to repository. Unfortunately git-clone doesn't clone remotes. Is there a way around it?

Comment: you found the way to solve this ?maybe make a script, and use a .gitremotes file similar to .gitmodules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make git repo remember all remotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286307/how-to-make-git-repo-remember-all-remotes)

Answer (score 5):

I begin this command

https://github.com/juanpabloaj/git-remote-init

for save the remotes in a .gitremotes file

Comment: nice script. I noticed that it assumes there are no remotes, and exits if there are any already defined. Do you typically bypass the default remote 'origin' that is set when you clone a repository? Otherwise this would of course exist after cloning and without doing anything special/non-standard, your script will return silently. Just curious about your workflow here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with git, as far as I know.

Telling users to run scripts post-clone is what people tend to do. If it's a ruby project, you probably have `rake`, for example, so you could have a `rake post_install` task.

Comment: Is there clone hook in git that could automatize it?

Comment: hooks get created locally when the repository is initialized by whatever implementation of Git is used to clone the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Remotes are saved in `.git/config` file of a repo, you can extract your favorites and append them on every clone.

Answer (score 1):

You could define them in your global config file `~/.gitconfig` instead of your project's `.git/config`.  Be careful though... if you run `git remote update` in a project it will pull down **all** remotes, even for repositories completely unrelated to the one you're working on.