# Remember multiple git remote urls after clone

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have one gitlab / github remote repo for reviewing the code and I want to use Heroku as a second git remote url to deploy my app.

It works fine when I `git remote add name url` and then `git push name branch`

**However:** When I want to clone the repository on another computer from gitlab, all the remote urls are gone, just only the gitlab url is left.

How can I send save all the remote URLs ?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct approach would be to add them to the new repository as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make git repo remember all remotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286307/how-to-make-git-repo-remember-all-remotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git remotes are part of the local repository's configuration, not part of the repository itself -- they are not included in a clone.

You could do this by writing and checking-in a script that, when run, sets up the desired remotes in your local repository, and then just remember to run it after cloning.